# We have $n$ balls and we randomly allocate them to $n$ buckets with equal probability. What is the probability that exactly one bucket remains empty?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a question with my reasoning (or lack thereof) -- I understand what the correct answer is, but I do not see the gap in my logic.

**Premise:**
We have $n$ balls and we randomly allocate them to $n$ buckets with equal probability. What is the probability that exactly one bucket remains empty?

**My Attempt:**
Let us start by determining the probability of allocating $n-1$ balls among $n$ buckets such that there is exactly one empty bucket.

As $n\over{n}$ of the buckets are initially empty, the first ball is always placed in an empty bucket (i.e. probability of $n\over{n}$). After placing the first ball, ${n-1}$ of $n$ buckets are empty, so the probability of placing the 2nd ball into an empty bucket is ${n-1}\over n$. This continues on for the $n-1$ balls as follows:

$$\text{P(Exactly One Bucket Empty)}= { n\over n} \times { n-1\over n} \times { n-2\over n} \times ...  \times { 2\over n} = {n! \over n^{n-1}}$$

Now we can multiply that probability by the probability that we allocate the final ball to one of the $n-1$ buckets that are already occupied. This should yield the probability of allocating $n$ balls among $n$ buckets such that exactly one bucket is empty.

The calculation is as follows:

$$ = {n! \over {n^{n-1}}} \times {{n-1}\over{n}} = {{{n!}\times(n-1)}\over{n^n}} = {{(n-1)! \times (n-1)}\over{n^{n-1}}}$$

**Problem with my answer:**
Most answers I have seen give the answer as:

$$={{(n-1)! \times (n-1)}\over{2n^{n-2}}}$$

So, I appear to be off by a factor of $n\over 2$. Any suggestions on where I made an error in my logic? Thank you.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What is that initial product meant to be equal to?  The left hand is blank.  In any case, you appear to be computing the probability that the first $n-1$ are placed in distinct bins and that the last one is then a duplicate, but that's not the same as what you were asked.

Comment: It’s better to use \cdot or \times instead of * for multiplication.

Comment: I suggest:  Since $n=3$ is the first case in which the values differ, write out the case $n=3$ explicitly.  there are only $3^3=27$ unrestricted ways to distribute, after all.  That should clarify the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have attempted to clarify my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any suggestions on where I made an error in my logic?

The problem with your logic is that you are introducing an extra restriction. You are allowing only the last ball to be paired with another ball. In other words you are forcing the last ball to necessarily be in the bin with $2$ balls. This is a restriction that the question doesn't have.

Here's how we can correct it. What you are doing with the last ball can be done with any of the $n$ balls. So multiply by $n$.

However, putting the $i^{th}$ ball in the bin containing the $j^{th}$ ball is the same as putting the $j^{th}$ ball in the bin containing the $i^{th}$ ball. So we need to divide by $2$.

So the correct answer would be

$$\frac{(n-1)(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}} \times \frac{n}{2} = \frac{(n-1)(n-1)!}{2 n^{n-2}}$$

---

**Response to OP's comment**

Let me rephrase your solution from the start. Perhaps it will help you gain an intuitive understanding.

Let's find the probability that $i^{\text{th}}$ ball ends up with the $j^{\text{th}}$ ball (as a pair) in one bin and the other balls go into separate bins. We will label this $P(E_{ij})$

For this, imagine placing each ball into a separate bin one by one, with one caveat. When we get to the $j^{\text{th}}$ ball, we hold on to it and move on to the next ball. at the end we will have placed $n-1$ balls in $n-1$ bins and we will have the $j^{\text{th}}$ ball with us. The probability for this is

$$\frac{n}{n} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n} \cdots \cdot \frac{2}{n} = \frac{n!}{n^{n-1}}$$

Now, the ball still with us ($j^{\text{th}}$) must go into one specific bin - that with the $i^{\text{th}}$ ball. The probability for this happening is $\dfrac{1}{n}$. Multiplying this with the above expression, we get

$$P(E_{ij}) = \frac{n!}{n^{n-1}} \times \frac{1}{n} = \frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}$$

As you can see $P(E_{ij})$ is a constant *independent* of $i$ and $j$. Now, to get the total probability for exactly one bin to be empty we need to add it for all pairs of balls. Or multiply it with the number of pairs possible, $\dfrac{n (n-1)}{2}$. So

$$\begin{align*}
P &= \frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}} \times \frac{n (n-1)}{2} \\[0.3cm]
&= \frac{(n-1)(n-1)!}{2n^{n-2}}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Okay I think I understand the issue, if not the intuition. Basically, the final term for which bucket the double occurs in could appear anywhere in the sequence.

So we need to do the following:

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ({ n\over n} \times { n-1\over n} \times { n-2\over n} \times ...  \times {i\over n} \times  ... \times { 2\over n}) =  {n! \over n^{n}} \times \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i =  {n! \over n^{n}} \times ((\sum_{i=0}^{n} i) -n)$ Which can then be simplified to the answer. Basically the summand is the probability of the "empty" bucket occurring at index $i$. We then sum these probabilities across all possible buckets.

Comment: I am not sure the summand is a good translation of what we are doing. Please see my edit above. Hope it helps with the intuition.

Answer (score 3):

From the $n$ labelled balls, pick one to double up. Arrange the remaining $n-1$ and pick a hole. Finally place the double. This gives a probability of

$$\frac{n(n-1)!n(n-1)}{2n^n}$$

with the factor of $2$ coming from the double appearing twice in each  calculation.

Comment: @trueblueanil; one is for the other ball in the bucket with two balls, and the other is the position of the gap.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you meant by 
"the double appearing twice in each calculation"

Comment: (+1), simple explanation !

Comment: minor alternative : pick 1 bucket to leave empty and pick 2 balls to partner into one fused unit, which means that you have $~(n-1)~$ units to permute over the (n-1) buckets to be used.  Demoninator goes to $~n^n,~$ and numerator goes to $~\displaystyle n \times \binom{n}{2} \times (n-1)!.$

Answer (score 0):

Using  the product of two multinomial coefficients gives a mechanical way (sparing the labor of thought) to compute arrangements of distinct balls in distinct boxes

$\text{[Lay Down Pattern] x [Permute]}$

With $n=5$ as an example, the number of arrangements where exactly $1$ box is enpty will be given by

$= \Large\frac{5!}{2!1!1!1!0!}\times\frac{{5!}}{1!3!1!}$

which (ignoring factorials of $1$ and $0$) generalises to $\Large\frac{n!n!}{2!(n-2)!} = \frac{n!n(n-1)}{2}$

and dividing by total possible arrangements $n^n$,

$Pr = \Large\frac{{n!}n(n-1)}{2n^n} = \frac{(n-1)!(n-1)}{2n^{n-2}}$

You can see clearly  why $2$ comes in the denominator, and why the exponent of $n$ is $(n-2)$

Answer (score 0):

We have $n$ balls, $n$ buckets
With $1$ empty bucket, we have $^nP_{n - 1}$ arrangements of the $n$ balls. Since any of the $n$ buckets can be empty, we have $n \times ^nP_{n - 1}$ permutations. The *extra/double* ball can be placed on any one of the $n - 1$ balls, giving us a total of $n(n - 1) \times ^nP_{n - 1}$ permutations.

If *all* buckets are filled, we have $^nP_n = n!$ permutations.

The *sample space* = $n(n - 1) \times ^nP_{n - 1} + n!$

$^nP_{n - 1} = n!$

The *sample space* = $n(n - 1) \times n! + n!$

The *event space* = $n(n - 1) \times n!$

The probability we're interested in = $P(E)$

$P(E) = \frac{n(n - 1) \times n!}{n(n - 1) \times n! + n!}$

$P(E) = \frac{n(n - 1)}{n(n - 1) + 1}$

With $2$ balls & $2$ buckets ...

1. Both buckets filled = 2 permutation
2. 1 bucket filled = 4 permutations

$P(1 \text{empty bucket}) = \frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2(2 - 1)}{2(2 - 1) + 1}$.

Checks out!!